# How to return a list from a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, point

So i need to get this "points" list in other class, but i actually cant get it anyhow. I know, maybe answer is obvious, but im really stuck here.

```
public List<Point> setDots(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    Point point1 = new Point(list.get(0), list.get(1));
    Point point2 = new Point(list.get(2), list.get(3));
    Point point3 = new Point(list.get(4), list.get(5));
    Point point4 = new Point(list.get(6), list.get(7));
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(point1);
    points.add(point2);
    points.add(point3);
    points.add(point4);
    return points;
}
```

and here is the class where i need to call it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Point userPoint = new Point(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()), Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));

    DotsReader dr = new DotsReader();
    dr.pointReader();

    DotsSetter ds = new DotsSetter();
    ds.setDots(dr.dots);
}
```

i need to compare if userPoint lie on the edge or in or out of the my square. Cant resolve it with my experience.
Got no errors, but cant find a way to catch returned "points" in main method.
Help me here please.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now? Do you get an error? Not desired output? Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]

Comment: `List<Point> theListYouWant = ds.setDots(dr.dots);`?

Comment: and where are you trying to call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call:

```
ds.setDots(dr.dots);
```

already returns what you need, you are just not memorizing it for future use. Just store it in a variable like this:

```
List <Point> points = ds.setDots(dr.dots);
```

and now you can use the variable `points`.